# Use action from a controller as filter in another controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I am trying to create an action that checks if a user is permitted to perform a certain action and if the user isn't then I want to redirect the user to an "Access Denied" view
This is how my current setup is

class PermissionController < ApplicationController

```
def authorize(permission_id)
   is_permitted = is_user_permitted(permission_id)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js { render :json => {:is_permitted => is_permitted, :redirect => url_for(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index' , notice: "No access")}}
     format.all  { redirect_to :controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index' , notice: "No access" unless is_permitted == true }
   end
end
```

end

I want to call the authorize action in the :before_filter of another controller.

How do I do that?

I can't put the authorize action in the ApplicationController since I want to define a route to this action in routes.rb

Comment: Just make a new controller with your authorize method that inherits application controller, and inherit the new controller wherever you need to use the authorized method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NickM has covered this in his comment... have `OtherController` inherit from `PermissionController`

```
class PermissionController < ApplicationController
  def authorize
    ...
  end
end

class OtherController < PermissionController
  before_filter :authorize
end
```

However I note your authorize method has a parameter?

You'll need to handle that in the before_filter clause.  Assuming you can store `permission_id` in a session variable...

```
class PermissionController < ApplicationController
  def authorize(permission_id)
    ...
  end
end

class OtherController < PermissionController
  before_filter { |controller| controller.authorize(session[:permission_id] }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this, assuming you have the user's id stored in session:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def current_user
        return unless session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    end

    def authorize

        # If user is NOT permitted
        if !is_user_permitted(current_user)

            # Response for you ajax here
            respond_to do |format|
                format.js { render :json => {:is_permitted => false, :redirect => url_for(:controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index' , notice: "No access")}}
                format.all  { redirect_to :controller => 'welcome', :action => 'index' , notice: "No access" }
            end
        end
    end
end


class SomeOtherChildController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authorize, :only => [:show, :new, :edit]
    # or you can use :except => [:index, :create, :destroy, :update] instead of :only.

    # No authorization required
    def index
    end

    # Authorization required
    def show
    end

    # Authorization required
    def new
    end

    # No authorization required
    def create
    end

    # Authorization required (Ajax response for your "Edit" button)
    def edit
         # authorize method in ApplicationController will be called first
         # If user is authorized, then the rest of this action will be executed
         respond_to do |format|
             format.js { render :json => {:is_permitted => true} }
         end
    end

    # No authorization required
    def update
    end

    # No authorization required
    def destroy
    end
end
```

Take this as an outline and general concept to what you might want to implement.

This is typically a concept I implement with permissions in my apps. You probably wouldn't want to put the Permissions logic in a separate child class controller, because in order to check permissions, you would either have to create a reference object of the PermissionsController (that is ugly and very un-Rails like) and use it within whatever controller you're trying to check permissions for, or you will have all other controller classes inherit from the PermissionsController, which isn't terrible, but certainly not ideal.

If users can have multiple types of permissions, you are probably better off creating a Permission model and controller, with a `User has_many Permissions` relationship, where the logic in the `authorize` method would become a bit easier to implement.

Comment: But I need the authorize function to respond to ajax calls from my view too. For e.g I have a say an edit button. When the user clicks on the edit button I want to call authorize to validate the user's permission. I'm a rails newbie but I couldn't find an example with routes defined to map to the application contoller actions

Comment: So based on my answer, if you were to click on the "Edit" button you mentioned, it should map to the edit action in your controller. If you specified that the edit action should require authorization by including it in the list of actions in the "before_filter :authorize, :only => [:edit]" call, it will first call the authorize method in the ApplicationController first and check if the user is authorized to do that action. If they are not, you could actually perform your "respond_to do format.js ... end" block there to respond to your Ajax calls application-wide.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit to reflect a bit more on my previous comment.